# raster: Count zeros points occurrence too in R

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I don't have sucess for count the number of points by pixel in a raster when I don't have points. In my example:

```
#Create a raster and some points
xmn = 17;xmx = 23;ymn=42;ymx=49
my_ras<-raster(matrix(1:12,3,4), xmx=xmx, xmn=xmn,ymx=ymx,ymn=ymn)
my_points<-data.frame(x=runif(10,xmn,xmx), y=runif(10,ymn,ymx))

#Count the points
pointcount<- rasterize(my_points, my_ras, fun='count')

#Vizualize
plot(my_ras)
points(my_points, pch=16)
d <- data.frame(coordinates(pointcount), count=pointcount[])
summary(d)
#       x               y             count      
# Min.   :17.75   Min.   :43.17   Min.   :1.000  
# 1st Qu.:18.88   1st Qu.:43.17   1st Qu.:1.000  
# Median :20.00   Median :45.50   Median :1.500  
# Mean   :20.00   Mean   :45.50   Mean   :1.667  
# 3rd Qu.:21.12   3rd Qu.:47.83   3rd Qu.:2.000  
# Max.   :22.25   Max.   :47.83   Max.   :3.000  
#                                 NA's   :6
```

Here, the problem is that I don't have the 0 values for pixels without points. I can't make a raster of zeros because in the real world in my rasters I have the `NA` values outside a target area and make this was cause mistakes between real zeros (without points) and zeros outside the area boundary.

I need the zeros and NA values if have (obviously in this case not), any ideas? Maybe the `sf` package has something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
library(raster)
xmn = 17;xmx = 23;ymn=42;ymx=49
ras <-raster(matrix(1:12,3,4), xmx=xmx, xmn=xmn,ymx=ymx,ymn=ymn)
points <-data.frame(x=runif(10,xmn,xmx), y=runif(10,ymn,ymx))
```

You can use `background=0` instead of NA

```
pointcount<- rasterize(points, ras, fun='count', background=0)
```

If you now want to exclude some areas, you can use `raster::mask`. Alternatively, if you have a raster with NA and zero values, you could use `rasterize` with `update=TRUE`